# Why the script can't be executed at stop?

Tags: init.d

The three lines can run.

```
debian8@hwy:~$ trafficlog="/var/log/traffic.log"
debian8@hwy:~$ echo  `date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S  "` |  sudo tee -a  $trafficlog    
2017-02-04 21:20:41
debian8@hwy:~$ sudo iptables  -v -L INPUT |grep Chain  |  sudo tee -a  $trafficlog
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 122 packets, 28381 bytes)
```

Let me check it.

```
debian8@hwy:~$ cat  /var/log/traffic.log
2017-02-04 21:20:41
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 122 packets, 28381 bytes)
```

Now to make it run at the runlevel6 on my debian8.

```
sudo vim /etc/init.d/K99trafficLog.sh
#!/bin/bash
trafficlog="/var/log/traffic.log"
echo  `date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S  "` |  sudo tee -a  $trafficlog
sudo iptables  -v -L INPUT |grep Chain  |  sudo tee -a  $trafficlog

sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/K99trafficLog.sh
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/K99trafficLog.sh  /etc/rc6.d/K99trafficLog
```

Now to test it.

```
echo "" | sudo tee /var/log/traffic.log
```

Then to reboot to verify.

```
sudo cat /var/log/traffic.log
```

It is unlucky that nothing written into /var/log/traffic.log,why?

Comment: `echo \`...\`` makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 2):

Those init scripts are run as root. Therefore you don't need all those sudo/tee hacks:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec >/var/log/traffic.log
date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S  "
iptables -v -L INPUT |grep Chain
```

Also be aware that `/etc/rc*.d/K*` is run on *leaving* runlevel, while `/etc/rc*.d/S*` is run on *entering* runlevel.

Be aware that runlevel 6 is special. Entering that runlevel makes your system reboot, therefore you never actually leave that level.

You can always manually debug your script using `sudo bash -x /etc/rc6.d/K99trafficLog`.

Also be aware that current debian systems use `systemd` for managing services. Please read about about systemd which handles things different than old runlevel based approaches.

Comment: To change your lines can't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/graphical.target.wants/Ktraffic.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Record net traffic

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash   /etc/init.d/K01trafficLog.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=poweroff.target
```

`sudo vim  /etc/init.d/K011trafficLog.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
trafficlog="/var/log/traffic.log"
date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S  "         >> $trafficlog
iptables  -v -L INPUT |grep Chain   >> $trafficlog
```

`systemctl enable ktraffic.service`